# scala-spark: How to filter RDD after groupby

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have started with a RDD that has pipe separated string. I have processed the data and gotten into following format:

```
((0001F46468,239394055),(7665710590658745,-414963169),0,1420276980302)
((0001F46468,239394055),(8016905020647641,183812619),1,1420347885727)
((0001F46468,239394055),(6633110906332136,294201185),1,1420398323110)
((0001F46468,239394055),(6633110906332136,294201185),0,1420451687525)
((0001F46468,239394055),(7722056727387069,1396896294),1,1420537469065)
((0001F46468,239394055),(7722056727387069,1396896294),1,1420623297340)
((0001F46468,239394055),(8045651092287275,-4814845),1,1420720722185)
((0001F46468,239394055),(5170029699836178,-1332814297),0,1420750531018)
((0001F46468,239394055),(7722056727387069,1396896294),0,1420807545137)
((0001F46468,239394055),(4784119468604853,1287554938),1,1421050087824)
```

Just to give an high level view on description of the data. You can think first element in the main tuple (first tuple) as a user identification, second tuple as a product identification, and third element is user's preference on the product. (for future reference I am going to mark above data set as `val userData`)

My goal is that if user has casted both positive (1) and negative (0) preference for a product only take the record with positive. For example:

```
((0001F46468,239394055),(6633110906332136,294201185),1,1420398323110)
((0001F46468,239394055),(6633110906332136,294201185),0,1420451687525)
```

I only want to keep

```
((0001F46468,239394055),(6633110906332136,294201185),1,1420398323110)
```

So I grouped the users by user-product tuple 
              `(0001F46468,239394055),(6633110906332136,294201185`

```
val groupedFiltered = userData.groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2)).map(u => {
      for(k <- u._2) {
        if(k._3 > 0)
          u
      }
    })
```

But that return empty tuples.

So I took the following approach:

```
val groupedFiltered = userData. groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2)).flatMap(u => u._2).filter(m => m._3 > 0)

((47734739656882457,-1782798434),(7585453414177905,-461779195),1,1422013413082)
((47734739656882457,-1782798434),(7585453414177905,-461779195),1,1422533237758)
((55218449094787901,-1374432022),(6227831620534109,1195766703),1,1420410603596)
((71212122719822610,-807015489),(6769904840922490,1642054117),1,1422549467554)
((75414197560031509,1830213715),(6724015489416254,-1389654186),1,1420196951100)
((60422797294995441,734266951),(6335216393920738,1528026712),1,1421161253600)
((35091051395844216,451349158),(8135854751464083,-1751839326),1,1422083101033)
((16647193023519619,990937787),(5384884550662007,-910998857),1,1420659873572)
((43355867025936022,-945669937),(7336240855866885,518993644),1,1420880078266)
((12188366927481231,-2007889717),(5336507724485344,363519858),1,1420827788022)
```

This was promising but it looks like its taking all the records that has zero where I only want if the user has 1 and 0 for same item only keep the one with 1.

Comment: Peter's answer is probably the best as it results in one item, whereas the other ways will result in more than one if there are more than one positive reviews. But, you are close, just change the first to flatMap and the for to a for yield...and yield k, not u

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could only keep the maximum user preference from the grouped results.

```
userData
 // group by user and product
 .groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2))
 // only keep the maximum user preference per user/product
 .mapValues(_.maxBy(_._3))
 // only keep the values
 .values
```

Comment: `toList` is not available for me from `values` wonder why is that..? is `toList` is necessary because after I do `.values` its already rdd right?

Comment: Just `values` will be OK in your case, yes.

Comment: This did work when I tried it but for some reason I am getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (null) [duplicate 1]` when right when I do the `groupBy`. Before creating a new question I thought I ll put a comment first to see. I was trying to wrap around how can `groupBy` can throw such error.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis I think you should indead open a new question with some more information about the input you are using when you get this error.